# I need to redirect my dynamic URL to a clean and SEO friendly static URL using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I am a web developer. I have developed a news portal for my client. But the URLs of the articles are dynamic and I need to redirect it to a static URL for SEO purpose.

The current URL : https://example.com/single-post.php?id=1&category=news&title=this-is-a-title

Desired URL : https://example.com/news/this-is-a-title

Someone please help me.

I have wrote this :

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)title=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?single-post\.php$ /%2/%1  [R=301]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/(\d+)$ single-post.php?title=$1&id=$2 [END]
```

But the URL output is not what I expected. It is like : 
https://example.com/this-is-title/?id=1&title=this-is-title

The only title came first without the id and then the old format came again after the slash. I can't understand what is going on here.

Comment: Please go read [ask]. You need to show us what you tried / researched so far, and describe your actual _problem_ to us.

Answer (score 0):

What you ask actually is not possible. There is no way for the rewriting module to somehow magically guess the numerical ID of that object you request. What you *can* actually do is publish URL in the style of `https://example.com/news/1/this-is-a-title`. Notice the ID in there, that is what is usally done. For that his should point you into the right direction:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?news/(\d+)/(.*)/?$ /single-post.php?id=$1&category=news&title=$2 [END]
```

Typically your application logic will only need the numerical ID of the requested object to fetch it from your database. So you typically can silently drop the title in the internal rewriting which makes things even more simple:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/?news/(\d+) /single-post.php?id=$1&category=news [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).

---

UPDATE:

in your comment to this answer you suggest to also do an explit redirection in case the target URL is used on the client side. Here is a variant of version 2 above which adds that redirection:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?single-post\.php$ /news/%1  [R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?news/(\d+) /single-post.php?id=$1&category=news [END]
```

A variant of version 1 would look similar:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)(?:&|$)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)title=([^&]+)(?:&|$)
RewriteRule ^/?single-post\.php$ /news/%1/%2  [R=301]

RewriteRule ^/?news/(\d+) /single-post.php?id=$1&category=news [END]
```

Is is a good idea to start with a 302 redirection first. And only change that to a 301 redirection once everything works fine. That saves you from hassles with client side caching while you are still trying things out.

Comment: I have tried it. It works. But there is another problem. I have to type the new URL manually to see the effects. But it should automatically redirect to the new URL as we hit the old URL. Please find a solution for that also. Thank you very much.

Comment: I added an UPDATE to the answer.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please check. I have faced a problem again.